# Load password recovery from SD card

Tags: windows-8.1, diskpart, bcdedit

**The problem**

I have an old Lenovo tablet (Lenovo IdeaPad Miix 10) that is running Windows 8.1. The tablet comes with a detachable keyboard, that seems to be broken - there is absolutely no reaction to the keystrokes. I have forgotten the password to my account, as it's an old tablet I was not using for a long time. The problem is, I want to use the tablet. Ideally, without loosing files, i.e. a fresh re-install is not preferred. I do not have a recovery point for Windows either.

**What I have attempted to do**

I have found a program that promises to erase my password: https://www.isunshare.com/windows-8-password/windows-8.1-password-reset-when-forgot-it.html

I've burned that software to a microSD card and inserted it into the tablet.

The tricky part is, I cannot press F2, F10 or whatever other key is used to enter BIOS to change the boot order of disks. So, I was messing with `bcdedit` and `diskpart` a lot, but to no success - the program for password recovery doesn't boot.

I've booted the tablet into troubleshooting mode and opened a `cmd`. Then I've used `diskpart`: my SD card is visible there. I've made it `active`.

With `bcdedit` I've created a new Windows Boot Loader entry off of the default one.

Now, I am not sure what I need to change in the properties of this newly created entry in order for the password recovery program to load correctly.

I've changed `device` to `partition=D:` (`D` is the letter for SD card I got from `diskpart`).

I don't know what to specify for the `path`. I've looked at the file tree of the burnt SD card:

```
.
├── boot
│   ├── bcd
│   ├── bootfix.bin
│   ├── boot.sdi
│   ├── bootsect.exe
│   ├── en-us
│   │   └── bootsect.exe.mui
│   ├── etfsboot.com
│   └── resources
│       └── bootres.dll
├── BOOTMGR
├── bootmgr.efi
├── efi
│   ├── boot
│   │   └── bootx64.efi
│   └── microsoft
│       └── boot
│           ├── bcd
│           ├── cdboot.efi
│           ├── cdboot_noprompt.efi
│           ├── efisys.bin
│           ├── efisys_noprompt.bin
│           └── resources
│               └── bootres.dll
├── sources
│   └── BOOT.WIM
└── System Volume Information
    ├── IndexerVolumeGuid
    └── WPSettings.dat

10 directories, 19 files
```

So, for the `patch` I've tried specifying `\BOOTMGR`, `\bootmgr.efi`, `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi` - all failed and the booting continued with a normal system to which I don't know a password to.

**Questions**

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. What is the minimal amount of info I need to specify for the Windows Boot Loader entry?
3. What do `device`, `path`, `osdevice` and `systemroot` mean and how do they relate to each other? What values do I need to assign to them in order to boot into this password recovery program?

Comment: Windows will go to Safe mode if you force shutdown repeatedly with the power button; perhaps the on-screen keyboard will activate. Also, check if the detachable keyboard requires batteries or charging.

Comment: If you can boot into Command mode, why not execute the program from there? Your link also has this command that might be simpler: `net user UserName NewPassword`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think I will try via `net user`.